# Make more lines fit on the page in the scrreprt class

Tags: margins, koma-script

Good to see this: "Documents built on scrreprt are highly customizable" (Stefan Kottwitz in his answer [How to customize the standard report template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/how-to-customize-the-standard-report-template/1219#1219)).

My question:
I want to make the top and bottom page margins smaller, by 1,5 cm each so that more lines fit on the page - how do I do this?

Does the following answer apply to scrreprt, too? [How do I change my margins and spacing to fit the PhD thesis requirements of University XYZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367/how-do-i-change-my-margins-and-spacing-to-fit-the-phd-thesis-requirements-of-univ/369#369)

Comment: Yes, the `geometry` package is able to change margins when using KOMA-Script. I suggest trying the adjustments by yourself to get the most satisfactory result.

Example:
`\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}`

Comment: I tried to improve the wording of your question and its title a bit. Hope the result is OK - if not, please tell me!

Comment: thanks, this is fine with me, peer review makes output better and this one is a good example of the advantages of post-publishing peer review

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't call the class-inherent features of KOMA-script "better" than `geometry` -- KOMA-script offers a typographically sound default layout plus minor customization abilities, while `geometry` allows for a multitude of layouts (including some that are outright ugly).

As Altermundus pointed out, one way to make more lines fit on the page is by setting KOMA-script's `DIV` option to, say, 12 (with 10 being the default value for A4 paper and a basic font size of 11pt). However, this will not only increase the number of lines, but also the length of single lines, which in turn will at some point hamper legibility. An alternative solution is to use `geometry` to increase the height, but not the width of the text area -- i.e, a layout that features different proportions of height vs. width for the paper size and the text area. Here's an example that combines A4 paper with a golden ratio text area:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[hscale=0.69,vscale=0.79,heightrounded,includehead]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: ok @lockstep, will keep that for the phase when I have passed my beginner's stage, thanks to @all

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to use the package "typearea" or to use some facilities directly inside the class `scrreprt`. In Koma-script documentation (scrguien.pdf or scrguide.pdf), you have paragraphs about "Paper Formats". It's not a good idea to remove 1.5cm without adapting the height and the size of page.
You need to look at the DIV option :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=12]{scrreprt}
```

You can also look at the option `BCOR`.

Comment: I believe the correct way to call these options is with `keyval` syntax. So `paper=A4,DIV=12`.

Comment: @Seamus you are right problem with cut paste for DIV but a4paper is valide , no ?

Comment: it's a valid option, yes. But I think I read that the preferred method of entering all options is now to use the keyval syntax. I don't think it matters though

Comment: @Seamus I agree completely with you.