# Page size problem

Tags: paper-size

I am writting my thesis book in LaTeX and I have a problem with the page size.

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,headinclude=true,footinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}

\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{../classicthesis}
```

The page borders space is too large when I print my document.
Are the a5paper sizes optimal for theses? Is better a4paper?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: The two "standards" are `letterpaper` and `a4paper`. `a5paper` is half of `a4paper`, which accounts for the seemingly large borders around your printout. Add `\usepackage{showframe}` to your preamble to see the actual borders, then modify to `a4paper` and do the same.

Comment: If your institution does not have a particular format to follow I suggest you to use the class `report` with `a4paper`.

Comment: note that the package `classicthesis` gives you quite wide borders in both a5 and a4. Which might be a good thing. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/why-are-default-latex-margins-so-big

The typearea package in the KOMA-Script can calculate your borders (see the scrguide)