# ShareLaTex's margins

Tags: sharelatex

I am a very beginning user of ShareLaTex. Generally I use only the most simple \documentclass{article} which is sufficient for my purpose. However, I consider the left-right top-bottom margins are too wide. How can I reduce them to 1" only?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Does `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` help?

Comment: You can use the geometry package to specify that, but beware most latex beginners make a similar comment but a few centuries of typographic tradition shows that increasing the text width makes the text a lot less legible.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131466/default-layout-is-not-as-expected/131496#131496

Comment: @yo': to David Carlisle and Yo': Thank you for your time! You have my question covered.