# Setting geometry as an option in my own class

Tags: geometry, documentclass-writing

I am writing a class. I want to set geometry with `geometry` package, but I get an error

```
! Package geometry Error: \paperwidth (0.0pt) too short.
```

My class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{probs}[2018/07/28]

\RequirePackage{geometry}

\DeclareOption{A5}{
    \geometry{
        paperheight =   8.27in,
        paperwidth  =   5.85in,
        top         =   0.5in,
        bottom      =   0.5in,
        outer       =   0.25in, 
        inner       =   0.25in,
        footskip    =   0.12in,
        headsep     =   0.12in,
        headheight  =   0.12in,
    }
}

\ExecuteOptions{A5}
\ProcessOptions
```

Testing file:

```
\documentclass[A5]{probs}


\begin{document}

Hello World!

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is actually not that difficult to set up the entire page geometry yourself.  The only tricky bit is that the "origin" is 1in below and to the right of the upper left corner, so you will have \topmargin=-.74in etc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo where can I find the list of lengths that need to be defined?

Comment: Its in the geometry manual.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131466/default-layout-is-not-as-expected/131477?s=21|0.0000#131477

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the style, but regarding the error message, you can use `\RequirePackage{geometry}` *after* having set the paper width and height.

Using

```
\setlength{\paperheight}{8.27in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{5.85in}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
```

works. You can set any height and width as it is adjusted by geometry afterwards. Full MWE:

```
%% probs.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{probs}[2018/07/28]

\setlength{\paperheight}{8.27in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{5.85in}
\RequirePackage{geometry}


\DeclareOption{A5}{
    \geometry{
        paperheight =   8.27in,
        paperwidth  =   5.85in,
        top         =   0.5in,
        bottom      =   0.5in,
        outer       =   0.25in, 
        inner       =   0.25in,
        footskip    =   0.12in,
        headsep     =   0.12in,
        headheight  =   0.12in,
    }
}

\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}

\ExecuteOptions{A5}
\ProcessOptions
```

and

```
%% doc.tex
\documentclass{probs}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\end{document}
```