# Lower the whitespace on each page at the top

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I just noticed that in my document every page consists of a large whitespace at the top. I have probably used some package that messed it up because I don't think it should be like this. How can I restore it to a normal spacing? Or what's normal?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an MWE?  Or even a screenshot of the output?  (A screenshot would basically tell us if it's normal / etc., but is hardly enough to actually fix the problem.)

Comment: We'll need to see more of what you're talking about. A "large whitespace at the top" is... not very clear.

Comment: @Werner Thank you. I've uploaded a picture.

Comment: That seems more-or-less normal, actually.  Can't quite tell from the picture of just the whitespace—not much of a reference point—but you might want to take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71172/17423.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `geometry` package to adjust margins etc.

E.g I have

```
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, includehead]{geometry}
\geometry{headheight=28pt, headsep=18pt}
```

in my thesis.

But without a MWE it is hard to know if that would conflict with some other packages you may be using....