# Why are default LaTeX TOP and BOTTOM margins so big?

Tags: formatting, margins, memoir

In the question [Why are default LaTeX margins so big?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/why-are-default-latex-margins-so-big), it is explained very well why the side margins have the large size they have (compared to most Word processors): The smaller line width provides a better reading experience. What is explained less well is why the **top and bottom margins** have the extraordinary size they have. Suppose I want to print a book in A5 format using the code

```
\documentclass[twoside,a5paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum,microtype}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\lipsum[1-22]
\end{document}
```

The result is seen below. The size of the side margins indeed makes the line width perfect for comfortable reading. But I do not see what justifies having the top and bottom margins account for almost half of the entire height of the page. **Why are the top and bottom margins so big in the standard page settings?**

[image]

Comment: The first one who writes "possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/why-are-default-latex-margins-so-big " goes directly to jail.

Comment: Have a look at the section about `typearea` in the KOMA-documentation as well as section 2 of the `memoir` doc.

Comment: Because [Van de Graaf Canon](http://theworldsgreatestbook.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Van_de_Graaf_canon_in_book_design1.png) ([and others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canons_of_page_construction)).

Comment: And is that canon important enough to waste half of the page?

Comment: @Gaussler it's as important as you want it to be; you're free to change the margins as you see fit. (La)TeX was _not_ designed to cram as much on a page as possible, but instead to produce aesthetically-pleasing documents. To do this, the creators looked to the prevailing design recommendations from high-quality print typesetting circles.

Comment: That was also my impression as well; I never doubted that there was a good reason for this format, however odd it seems to me. Yet I believe I have never in my life seen a novel (even from the finest of publishers) that was typeset using that canon. Any good ideas why?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/why-are-default-latex-margins-so-big

Comment: @DavidCarlisle goes directly to jail.

Comment: And please notice that I mention explicitly that my question is meant as an additional question to that other one, asking about something that was *not* covered well in that question.

Comment: This is I think one for [GraphicDesign.SE]. Note that the other question is older than the GD.SE site so it's righteously here. In general, there are only two answers to this question: (1) typography tradition (i.e., the question belongs o the other site) or (2) you gotta ask the memoir authors because only they can know (which means that it's "blatantly off-topic"). But it's only my opinion...

Comment: regarding the relationship of margins to the content of the page, [some comments by hermann zapf](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-1-2/tb70zapf.pdf) might interest you; this tugboat article is a translation of an article in dante's "die texnische komödie. the relevant pages are 28-29.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the choice of the document class designer, of memoir in this case. Although your title mentions default margins, you show memoir which has a larger margin it seems to me:

[image]

```
%\documentclass[twoside,a5paper]{memoir}
\documentclass[twoside,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,microtype}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\lipsum[1-22]
\end{document}
```