# How to format a long polynomial

Tags: math-mode

I have a long polynomial:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}% Loaded by mathtools
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$ f(z)=\frac{1}{382112640}(-306772802511648469920\eta^4z^4+762453974480763801600\eta^5z^4-1678626210368271790080\eta^5z^3-28510918043555533736160\eta^4z^3+11443138641451067779872\eta^3z^3-52164076923190540413504\eta^2z^2-78145258181161076156160\eta^5z^2-211306163712129371808450\eta^4z^2+228927087397104405937944\eta^3z^2+999881065017543109136462\eta^3z-317254092617698017425280\eta^5z-443761561344388063474665\eta^4z+82327155732241730770824\eta z-514623285385260545505123\eta^2z-1010535343560043404912120\eta^2-357788302700438191196160\eta^5-43808044579418934376632-214023244873618345872240\eta^4+11818373349781028\\
079\eta^3+347370177721463765064153\eta)/((417420z^2-4169121z-15571312)(1546z+3537)(3092z+17001))$
\end{document}
```

How do I format such a long polynomial correctly?

Comment: For anyone reaching this question in the future, I would strongly recommend writing a simple summation formula with coefficients $a_{i,j}$ and then adding a table to show the values.

Comment: @Mefitico It is a nice option! Why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @JouleV: Because it wouldn't answer the question. Ever heard of the patient who went to the doctor and said: *"It hurts when I do this"*, to which the doctor responded: *"Then don't do this!"*

Comment: @Mefitico No, it is still an appropriate expression of the equation, in my opinion. You can see that my answer and egreg's answer use indirect expressions, and you are talking about an indirect expression.

Answer (score 14):

I would use something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}% Loaded by mathtools
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Blah blah
\[f(z)=\frac{1}{382112640}\cdot\frac{A}{B}\]
where
\begin{align*}
    A=&\,-306772802511648469920\eta^4z^4+762453974480763801600\eta^5z^4\\
    &\,-1678626210368271790080\eta^5z^3-28510918043555533736160\eta^4z^3\\
    &\,+11443138641451067779872\eta^3z^3-52164076923190540413504\eta^2z^2\\
    &\,-78145258181161076156160\eta^5z^2-211306163712129371808450\eta^4z^2\\
    &\,+228927087397104405937944\eta^3z^2+999881065017543109136462\eta^3z\\
    &\,-317254092617698017425280\eta^5z-443761561344388063474665\eta^4z\\
    &\,+82327155732241730770824\eta z-514623285385260545505123\eta^2z\\
    &\,-1010535343560043404912120\eta^2-357788302700438191196160\eta^5\\
    &\,-43808044579418934376632-214023244873618345872240\eta^4\\
    &\,+11818373349781028079\eta^3+347370177721463765064153\eta
\end{align*}
and
\[B=(417420z^2-4169121z-15571312)(1546z+3537)(3092z+17001)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you could format this even more compactly by using matrix multiplication to express `A`

Answer (score 11):

I suggest something line the following, so the wide terms are reduced.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}% Loaded by mathtools
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{align*}
g(\eta,z)&=
\parbox[t]{0.85\displaywidth}{\raggedright
$-306772802511648469920\eta^4z^4+
762453974480763801600\eta^5z^4-
1678626210368271790080\eta^5z^3-
28510918043555533736160\eta^4z^3+
11443138641451067779872\eta^3z^3-
52164076923190540413504\eta^2z^2-
78145258181161076156160\eta^5z^2-
211306163712129371808450\eta^4z^2+
228927087397104405937944\eta^3z^2+
999881065017543109136462\eta^3z-
317254092617698017425280\eta^5z-
443761561344388063474665\eta^4z+
82327155732241730770824\eta z-
514623285385260545505123\eta^2z-
1010535343560043404912120\eta^2-
357788302700438191196160\eta^5-
43808044579418934376632-
214023244873618345872240\eta^4+
11818373349781028079\eta^3+
347370177721463765064153\eta$
}
\\[2ex]
h(z)&=(417420z^2-4169121z-15571312)(1546z+3537)(3092z+17001)
\end{align*}
\\[2ex]
f(z)=\frac{1}{382112640}\frac{g(\eta,z)}{h(z)}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your answer is OK, but some terms are out of pages margins.

Comment: @Nick Without knowing the line width you're using it's difficult to say more.

Comment: @Nick egreg's answer uses default margin of `article`, which is already [really big](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71172/156344). But it doesn't fit your margin?

Comment: I have moved the signs "-, +" from lines end and put them under sign "=".

Answer (score 9):

Given the nature of the operations, you can probably express this in a tidy manner using matrix multiplication notation, eg:

[image]

where:

[image]

Code:

```
$$ f(z)=\frac{1}{382,112,640} \; \frac{g(\eta, z)}{u(z) \, v(z) \, w(z) } $$

where

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
  g(\eta, z) = 
  \begin{bmatrix} 
    \begin{array}{r @{\hspace{0em}} r}
      - & 306,772,802,511,648,469,920 \\
        & 762,453,974,480,763,801,600 \\
      - & 1,678,626,210,368,271,790,080 \\
      - & 28,510,918,043,555,533,736,160 \\
       & 11,443,138,641,451,067,779,872 \\
      - & 52,164,076,923,190,540,413,504 \\
      - & 78,145,258,181,161,076,156,160 \\
      - & 211,306,163,712,129,371,808,450 \\
       & 228,927,087,397,104,405,937,944 \\
       & 999,881,065,017,543,109,136,462 \\
      - & 317,254,092,617,698,017,425,280 \\
      - & 443,761,561,344,388,063,474,665 \\
       & 82,327,155,732,241,730,770,824 \\
      - & 514,623,285,385,260,545,505,123 \\
      - & 1,010,535,343,560,043,404,912,120 \\
      - & 357,788,302,700,438,191,196,160 \\
      - & 43,808,044,579,418,934,376,632 \\
      - & 214,023,244,873,618,345,872,240 \\
       & 11,818,373,349,781,028,079 \\
       & 347,370,177,721,463,765,064,153
    \end{array}
  \end{bmatrix}^T
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{array}{l}
      \eta^4z^4 \\
      \eta^5z^4 \\
      \eta^5z^3 \\
      \eta^4z^3 \\
      \eta^3z^3 \\
      \eta^2z^2 \\
      \eta^5z^2 \\
      \eta^4z^2 \\
      \eta^3z^2 \\
      \eta^3z \\
      \eta^5z \\
      \eta^4z \\
      \eta z \\
      \eta^2z \\
      \eta^2 \\
      \eta^5 \\
      1 \\
      \eta^4 \\
      \eta^3 \\
      \eta
    \end{array}
  \end{bmatrix}
  & 
  \begin{array}{l}
    u(z) = \begin{bmatrix} \begin{array}{r @{\hspace{0em}} r} & 417,420 \\ - & 4,169,121 \\ - & 15,571,312 \end{array}\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} \begin{array}{l} z^2 \\ z \\ 1 \end{array}\end{bmatrix}\\[3em]
    v(z) = \begin{bmatrix} \begin{array}{r @{\hspace{0em}} r}  & 1,546 \\ & 3,537 \end{array}\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{l} z \\ 1 \end{array}\end{bmatrix}\\[3em]
    w(z) = \begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{r @{\hspace{0em}} r}  & 3,092 \\ & 17,001 \end{array}\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{l} z \\ 1 \end{array}\end{bmatrix} \\[3em]
  \end{array}
\end{array}
$$
```

---

PS. Having said that, given the nature of the numbers involved, I would also agree with Mefitico's point of view in the comments, i.e. it's best to create a variable with indices and express via a cleaner expression, and then refer to a table mapping those indices to the actual numbers involved.

Comment: The round brackets in the definitions of $u$, $v$ and $w$ seem superfluous.

Comment: From the point of view of someone wishing or needing to use such a polynomial, it would be helpful to insert breaks in all the long numbers to ease readability.

Comment: @jochen thanks, updated

Comment: @JeremyC thanks, updated. I went for comma delimiters rather than breaks, as that might have been misleading in the context of matrix notation.

Answer (score 6):

or

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}% Loaded by mathtools
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multline*}\medmath
f(z)=\frac{1}{382112640}
    \frac{\left[
    \begin{multlined}
    -306772802511648469920\eta^4z^4+762453974480763801600\eta^5z^4-\\
    1678626210368271790080\eta^5z^3-28510918043555533736160\eta^4z^3+\\
    11443138641451067779872\eta^3z^3-52164076923190540413504\eta^2z^2-\\
    78145258181161076156160\eta^5z^2-211306163712129371808450\eta^4z^2+\\
    228927087397104405937944\eta^3z^2+999881065017543109136462\eta^3z-\\
    317254092617698017425280\eta^5z-443761561344388063474665\eta^4z+\\
    82327155732241730770824\eta z - 514623285385260545505123\eta^2z-\\
    1010535343560043404912120\eta^2-357788302700438191196160\eta^5-\\
    43808044579418934376632-214023244873618345872240\eta^4+\\
    11818373349781028079\eta^3+347370177721463765064153\eta
    \end{multlined}\right]}
    {(417420z^2-4169121z-15571312)(1546z+3537)(3092z+17001)}
    \end{multline*}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend aligning the variables and adding some form of thousand-separators, both will enhance the readability. What I also recommend (but didn't do here) is sorting by the powers of the first and then the second variable. This is a modification of [JuleV's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483304/38199) answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}% Loaded by mathtools
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Blah blah
\[f(z)=\frac{1}{382112640}\cdot\frac{A}{B}\]
where
\[
\arraycolsep=0.5pt
\begin{array}{rrllrll}
    A=&\,      -306\,772\,802\,511\,648\,469\,920 &\eta^4 &z^4 &      +762\,453\,974\,480\,763\,801\,600 &\eta^5 &z^4\\
    &\,     -1\,678\,626\,210\,368\,271\,790\,080 &\eta^5 &z^3 &  -2\,8510\,918\,043\,555\,533\,736\,160 &\eta^4 &z^3\\
    &\,    +11\,443\,138\,641\,451\,067\,779\,872 &\eta^3 &z^3 &  -5\,2164\,076\,923\,190\,540\,413\,504 &\eta^2 &z^2\\
    &\,    -78\,145\,258\,181\,161\,076\,156\,160 &\eta^5 &z^2 & -21\,1306\,163\,712\,129\,371\,808\,450 &\eta^4 &z^2\\
    &\,   +228\,927\,087\,397\,104\,405\,937\,944 &\eta^3 &z^2 & +99\,9881\,065\,017\,543\,109\,136\,462 &\eta^3 &z\\
    &\,   -317\,254\,092\,617\,698\,017\,425\,280 &\eta^5 &z   & -44\,3761\,561\,344\,388\,063\,474\,665 &\eta^4 &z\\
    &\,    +82\,327\,155\,732\,241\,730\,770\,824 &\eta   &z   & -51\,4623\,285\,385\,260\,545\,505\,123 &\eta^2 &z\\
    &\,-1\,010\,535\,343\,560\,043\,404\,912\,120 &\eta^2 &    & -35\,7788\,302\,700\,438\,191\,196\,160 &\eta^5 &\\
    &\,    -43\,808\,044\,579\,418\,934\,376\,632 &       &    & -21\,4023\,244\,873\,618\,345\,872\,240 &\eta^4 &\\
    &\,         +11\,818\,373\,349\,781\,028\,079 &\eta^3 &    & +34\,7370\,177\,721\,463\,765\,064\,153 &\eta   &
\end{array}
\]
and
\[B=(417\,420z^2-4\,169\,121z-15\,571\,312)(1\,546z+3\,537)(3\,092z+17\,001)\]
\end{document}
```

I'm sure there are also some custom packages that can do this for you but this is just using the packages you provided:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following the original disposition of the function, but using `alignat`, parenthesis, and fractions to emphasize its different terms.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
& f(z) && = \frac{1}{382112640} \times \left( \vphantom{\frac{1}{382112640}} -306772802511648469920 \eta^4 z^4 + 762453974480763801600 \eta^5 z^4 \right. \\[1.5ex] 
& && -1678626210368271790080 \eta^5 z^3 -28510918043555533736160 \eta^4 z^3 \\[1.5ex]
& && +11443138641451067779872 \eta^3 z^3 -52164076923190540413504 \eta^2 z^2 \\[1.5ex]
& && -78145258181161076156160 \eta^5 z^2 -211306163712129371808450 \eta^4 z^2 \\[1.5ex]
& && +228927087397104405937944 \eta^3 z^2 +999881065017543109136462 \eta^3 z \\[1.5ex]
& && -317254092617698017425280 \eta^5 z -443761561344388063474665 \eta^4 z \\[1.5ex]
& && +82327155732241730770824 \eta z -514623285385260545505123 \eta^2 z \\[1.5ex]
& && -1010535343560043404912120 \eta^2 -357788302700438191196160 \eta^5 \\[1.5ex]
& && -43808044579418934376632 -214023244873618345872240 \eta^4 \\[1.5ex]
& && +11818373349781028079 \eta^3 +347370177721463765064153\eta \left. \vphantom{\frac{1}{382112640}} \right) \\[1.5ex]
& && \times \frac{1}{(417420z^2-4169121z-15571312)(1546z+3537)(3092z+17001)}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: fig]

Comment: Do you think this fits the page margin?

Comment: It fitted for me. An alternative is to add \\ to the last line to bring the last multiplication and fraction to an additional line.

Comment: In the original question, the term **417420z^2-4169121z-15571312** is in denominator, not in the numerator as you place it.

Comment: OK. I will revise this.

Comment: Revised the members of the last fraction. Also added a line for the last term (which also ensures that the display will fit the margins).

Answer (score 0):

I would usually use the package `breqn`. That automatically line-breaks equations, and has a lot of very nice features, but uses low-level having into the maths primitives, which means it tends to make a mess of other packages what do the same thing (for example, you can't use both `breqn` and `sansmath` in the same document)

```
\begin{dmath*}
f(z)=\frac{1}{382112640}\times-306772802511648469920\eta^4z^4+\left(762453974480763801600\eta^5z^4-1678626210368271790080\eta^5z^3-28510918043555533736160\eta^4z^3+11443138641451067779872\eta^3z^3-52164076923190540413504\eta^2z^2-78145258181161076156160\eta^5z^2-211306163712129371808450\eta^4z^2+228927087397104405937944\eta^3z^2+999881065017543109136462\eta^3z-317254092617698017425280\eta^5z-443761561344388063474665\eta^4z+82327155732241730770824\eta z-514623285385260545505123\eta^2z-1010535343560043404912120\eta^2-357788302700438191196160\eta^5-43808044579418934376632-214023244873618345872240\eta^4+11818373349781028079\eta^3+347370177721463765064153\eta\right)\times\left(\left(417420z^2-4169121z-15571312\right)\left(1546z+3537\right)\left(3092z+17001\right)\right)^{-1}
\end{dmath*}
```

which produces [image: this huge equation]

IMO the right-alignment is ugly but apparently that's the AMS standard - without the brackets it left aligns all those lines like the `alginat` version.