# how to reduce margins on left side in report

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I want to generate a pdf with my thesis when I compile the things to generated pdf.
What I see is that on left side a lot of space is left. 
[image: blank space in left side]

I am not clear in latex how do we reduce the margins on left side.

Comment: We cannot do anything with images. Please provide code so we know what you are doing. You must have done something to the margins because the margins does not normally look like that on the right. Note that having such small margins on the right (and on the left) is generally not a good idea as very long lines are very hard to read.

Comment: @daleif hi please see the full code https://github.com/kiotie32/arbit-text I do not know which section should I post here, I generated pdf from this. It has a template on which I worked.

Comment: note that decreasing the margins means making the text line longer and this will make the document unreadable if you change it by very much. It is not that the margins are over-large it is that A4 is very large for one-column text at 10pt.

Comment: [why are default latex margins so big](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/why-are-default-latex-margins-so-big/71211#71211)

Comment: Note we generally don't go to external sites for code as links rot over time and thus your question will not help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm%,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm,right=0.5cm
]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    content...
\end{document}
```

Remove % if you want to set all side margins.