# geometry package can't change margin in article document

Tags: margins

I am using `article` document class and I want to narrow down the margin.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=50mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\section{Trigonometric and hyperbolic equations}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \( 1 + \tan^2 x = \sec^2 x , \quad 1 + \cot^2 x = \csc^2 x \)
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled pdf. Notice the very wide margin on top, left and right.]

Questions:

1. How to correctly narrow down margin in `article` document?
2. Why the heck does `article` generate such a giant ugly margin? What's the reason and logic?

Comment: Try 5mm instead of 50mm.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. It's just not that sensible. Dummy question...

Comment: if you have smaller margins on A4 paper the line length is unreadably long.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/why-are-default-latex-margins-so-big/71211#71211