# Proper formatting, reference request

Tags: overleaf

I am currently trying to format my first LaTeX project.
I am writing in overleaf, and it is working just fine, but I am a little bit lost in finding good references which do not have hundrets of pages, so I am at the moment a little bit lost in the overwhelming tutorials and literature.

My settings are as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{Something}
\date{1.1.2011}
\maketitle
\begin{document}
hhh
\end{document}
```

I would like to have title and date in the upper left, or right corner.
Also I find that the space between the written words, and the edge of the paper is way to much.
How can this be shortend?

I am very thankful for any kind of advice, reference or alternative settings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you read the documentation for KOMA-Script, because you are using one class of it?

Comment: I do not know about KOMA-Script. I have taken these specific settings from a youtube tutorial.

Comment: `\maketitle`  should be behind `\begin{document}`. Your document errors. But beside this: the class defines how `\maketitle `  prints the title. So you should check the documentation, scrguide.pdf

Comment: before you change the margins (easily done with the `geometry` package) see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/why-are-default-latex-margins-so-big/71211#71211