# \documentclass{article} change text width

Tags: margins, textwidth

The default margins of this document class are too big, or the textwidth is not wide enough by default.
I prefer having ~80 char per line.

I really don't know how to widen this.

Which command and how to use preferably in my case?

I guess it's a simple thing to do, I'm just still very ignorant with regards to tex stuff...

**edit**:
I first tried `\setwidth` but it unbalanced my margins left and right.
`geometry` does the better job, I use the width option there.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the `geometry` package

Comment: geometry package but the margins are not too big https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/why-are-default-latex-margins-so-big