# memoir margins setup

Tags: margins, memoir

I wrote a little "book" by using the Memoir class.
I'd need to have no more than 35 chars per line and no more than 70 chars on a columns.

Is there some kind of settings to choose the best page layout based on the former
requirements? If not, is there some other way to correctly change the default margins side?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Related: [Best ratios of number of letters per line and of number of lines per page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14348/5764)

Comment: Are you asking for the [Average number of characters in one line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67694/average-number-of-characters-in-one-line)?

Comment: Well, the requirements are strict, then I can't use the "book recommendations for typography".
I'm asking how to choose my preferred margins setup using memoir class: for example, margin notes are not admitted by the requirements then I'd like to have symmetric margins on both odd and even pages, so that the typeblock is horizontally aligned to center.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Max 35 characters per line I think I understand but "no more then 70 chars on a columns" just does not make sense to me. Sometimes it's not so easy for bear of very little brain. Maybe you would be so kind to explain it again for me?

Comment: Well, requirements are strange for me too... however, the maximum number of rows per page is 70, and the maximum number of charaters per row is 35.
Using "default" memoir margins and 14pt size with roman character family does not achieve these requirements.
Then, i'd like to set some "greater" margins to reduce the number of rows and the number of characters per row.
I'd also like to have symmetric margins even using twoside and openright options.
Any idea?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Currently the question is marked with a duplicate flag. If you want to keep the question open can you distinguish and incorporate the differences into your question? Otherwise it will be closed as a duplicate

Comment: @percusse: which is the duplicated question? the copy is my question and my comment? I'd like to close mine or incorporate the differences but it's not clear for me which is the copied question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's flagged with what Werner has linked to in the comments.

Comment: Well, maybe the question is related to what Werner has linked to in the comments, but the question was not "what's the best number of rows/cols in a page?" nor "what's the best margin ratio?".
The question was "How to force custom margins or custom typeblock size?"
My difficulty was about the space left for margin notes.
Setting \setmarginnotes{0mm}{0mm}{0mm}, pdfLatex says Error: \marginparsep is zero or negative. I solved setting \setmarginnotes{1mm}{1mm}{\onelineskip}, but i don't think it's a best practise.

Comment: In fact i'm getting some warnings as: Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [].
Thank you for your attention.