# How can I keep less blank space on two sides?

Tags: margins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my margins and spacing to fit the PhD thesis requirements of University XYZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367/how-do-i-change-my-margins-and-spacing-to-fit-the-phd-thesis-requirements-of-uni)

My Latex file looks like the following:e

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[english, finnish, swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eurosym} % To get a euro sign: \euro{}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0},citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}


\raggedbottom%Do.
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
%\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{6pt}
\usepackage[belowskip=-15pt,aboveskip=0pt]{caption}
\setlength{\intextsep}{10pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\parskip 1ex
\parindent 0pt

%All the words with special hyphenation:
\hyphenation{di-gi-taa-li-sta yksi-suun-tai-sta}


\hyphenpenalty=5000
\tolerance=1000

% Command

\begin{document}
\evensidemargin 19mm
\oddsidemargin 19mm
\textwidth 155mm

%%%%%%%%%%     PREAMBLE + DOC SETTINGS ENDS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% By default, only up to 3rd level headers are numbered (e.g. 1.2.2.)
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % what headers are numbered
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} %what headers are put in the TOC

%% -------------- ABSTRACT --------------
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\input{abstract_english}


% -------------- ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS & TOC --------------

\input{acknowledgement}


%\clearpage

\newpage
{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont \tableofcontents}

\newpage
\phantomsection \label{listoftab}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

\newpage
\phantomsection \label{listoffig}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage

\newpage
\phantomsection \label{listofacronyms}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbreviations and Acronyms}
\input{acronyms}
\cleardoublepage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% The main content starts here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\parskip1ex
\parindent0mm

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{headings}

\input{chapter1}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{mySources}

\label{pages-text}
\end{document}
```

Please forgive me if it looks a little more complicated that it should. It looks like this because its a common template for Masters Thesis.

Now the output looks like:

[image]

Now u should see that, there are too much space on both sides of the text. How may I reduce it and make the text wider?

Bye.

Comment: The easiest way to adjust page dimensions is to use the `geometry` package. I imagine this question has to be a duplicate of something, so don't be offended if it gets closed :)

Comment: This one looks pretty close [how-do-i-change-my-margins-and-spacing-to-fit-the-phd-thesis-requirements-of-uni](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367/how-do-i-change-my-margins-and-spacing-to-fit-the-phd-thesis-requirements-of-uni)

Comment: This looks about right for me. For readability LaTeX documents normally have large margins so that the text is not long. Maximum line width for readability should be less than 1.5-2 alphabets. Another reason for wide margins for theses is that most of them end up in files or are bound in spiral bounds. If you still need to adjust use the geometry package.

Comment: For info, the question has been cross-posted: [How can I keep less blank space on two sides](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=20252).